# How do I enable webhdfs through Cloudera Manager?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, cloudera

Cloudera rolled webhdfs into latest cd3u4 but I'm not able to find where I can enable this feature.  I realize there's an entry dfs.webhdfs.enabled you can manually edit in hdfs-site.xml.  Within cdh3 distribution, is there a safe place where I can place dfs.webhdfs.enabled configuration?  Can someone help point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use WebHDFS, you must first enable it.

How? Set the following property in conf/hdfs-site.xml:

```
<property>
  <name>dfs.webhdfs.enabled</name>
  <value>true</value>
</property>
```

Note:
If you want to use WebHDFS in a secure cluster, you must set additional properties to configure secure WebHDFS. If you are using SPNEGO security, see Configure secure WebHDFS in Configuring Hadoop Security in CDH3 (SPNEGO). If you are using KSSL security, see Configure secure WebHDFS in Configuring Hadoop Security in CDH3 (KSSL).

I found it here: https://ccp.cloudera.com/display/CDHDOC/CDH3+Deployment+on+a+Cluster#CDH3DeploymentonaCluster-EnablingWebHDFS

Comment: For CDH4 the answer is here: https://ccp.cloudera.com/display/CDH4DOC/Deploying+HDFS+on+a+Cluster#DeployingHDFSonaCluster-EnablingWebHDFS